# How to call a method from another project in php

Tags: php

I have this method in a php file in project_A

```
function newComponent ($name)  
{  
echo 'Hello '.$name;  
}
```

and i want to call it from another php file in another project: project_B

how could i use the method in it?

Comment: What do you mean by "project"? Are they on same server or not?

Comment: RTFM about 'include' and maybe PSR4 about autoading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First include that file and then call it

```
<?php

include_once 'file1.php';

myfuntion(); //function of file 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You include() or require() your project_A php file in project_B.